# How to remove ANSI-Code ("&#13;") from string in PHP

Tags: php, string, ascii

I have tried a lot but nothing is working. I want to import a XML-file with PHP. In some strings the customer puts some ANSI-Code Carrier Returns ("&#13;"). I have tried to remove them with:

```
str_replace('\r', '', $xml->description);
```

I also tried it with `"&\#13;"`, `"\r\n"`, `"\&\\#13\;"` in the search but nothing works. Do you have any idea how to remove these linebreaks?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "\r" instead of '\r'?

Comment: @safarov Those aren't multibyte characters.

Comment: yes, i have tried it with double-quotes

Comment: @corbin: ok you are right with the double quotes! But i have to search for \r\n. I only did it with single-qoutes. THANKS!

Comment: have gone ahead and posted it as an answer then :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your XML processor is already handling de-entitying the entities, you'll be left over with plain ASCII \n or \r or \r\n.  PHP does not handle \r or \n inside of single quotes.  It only translates them to their respective characters (codes 10 and 13), when the \r and \n are inside of double quotes.

You just need to use "\n" or maybe "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

Should just be a simple case of:

```
str_replace('&#13;', '', $xml->description);
```

Notice I haven't escaped the `#` with a `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, This runs just fine

```
$str = "&\#13;"; //just an example

echo str_replace("&\\#13;", "hello", $str);
```

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/1MLiS)

Comment: thanks. But that won't work for me. It seems to be not the same.

Comment: @ESCOBAR, Paste your XML file in the paste bin, Let me take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
str_replace("\x13", '', $str);
```

I'm using the hexcode for that char.